# Same keystore but different fingerprints

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, android-keystore

I just took over an existing application and would like to publish an update.

The developer gave me the keystore, however, when I try to publish the APK in Google Play, I can't. Google tells me the fingerprints are not the same.

The old fingerprint was:

```
[SHA1: 60:myPrint:14, SHA1: 8B:secondPrint:57]
```

and the new one is:

```
[SHA1: 60:myPrint:14]
```

The former developer used Netbeans and I use Eclipse. Has anyone ever had this problem?